# Filtering AWS SQS Tags using JQ

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-sqs

I'm having doubts when trying to run a query with JQ.
I have an SQS queue with Tags applied and when I run

`aws sqs list-queue-tags --region sa-east-1 --queue-url <my-url-queue> --output json | jq`

returns the output:

```
{
  "Tags": {
    "owner": "foo",
    "Name": "bar-queue"
  }
}
```

So...I just filter using like this:

`aws sqs list-queue-tags --region sa-east-1 --queue-url <my-url-queue> --output json | jq '.Tags[] | [.Name]'`

or

`aws sqs list-queue-tags --region sa-east-1 --queue-url <my-url-queue> --output json | jq '.Tags[].Name'`

and other methods without success, always output: `jq: error (at <stdin>:6): Cannot index string with string "Name"`

Maybe I'm having a noobie hahaha, but someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take heart, I've been struggling with JMESPath query expressions for the past couple of years!  It's been a long time getting used to them.

In your example output, `Tags` is a JSON object rather than a list, so the `[]` in your JMESPath expression is causing the error.  Try this as your `jq` command:

```
jq '.Tags.Name'
```

You'll get:

```
"bar-queue"
```

You can use the `-r` option to `jq` to get the output without quotes.

However I think you can do better by having the `aws` command do this filtering for you.  Try the `--query` option:

```
aws sqs list-queue-tags --region sa-east-1 --queue-url <my-url-queue> --query 'Tags.Name'
```

Yes, the expression for the `aws` command doesn't have the leading `.`.  If you don't want the quotes around the output, add the option `--output text`.

---

*Edited to add these notes about JMESPath expressions for jq vs. aws:*

The leading `.` character isn't the only difference between expressions that `jq` likes and the ones the `aws` command likes.  I don't have an exhaustive list, but I have needed to use different quotes around path names for one program than I used for the other.

There are pretty good tutorials on query expressions for each of these programs:

- **jq** : https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/
- **aws** : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html

And a website that's useful for interactively trying out expressions, once you've figured out how the site works:  https://jmespath.org .  It includes a link to another, more general tutorial.

Comment: Great bro, thanks for the explanation, both examples works fine!